# Bootstrap centering item in navbar when other items are right-aligned

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm currently making a webpage and am using a navbar using Bootstrap. I have three icons aligned on the right, and I want to align another item in the center. However, using mx-auto doesn't center it in the middle of the webpage and shifts it left a little bit because of the icons on the right. The code is below:

```
 <nav class="navbar bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-brand mx-auto order-0" href="#">
        <a class="rainbow" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model" target="_blank">color</a>dle
      </div>

      <div class="ms-auto order-3">
        <button class="icons settings-icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i></button>
        <button class="icons leaderboard-icon"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i></button>
        <button class="icons question-icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-chart-simple"></i></button>
      </div>



    </div>
  </nav>
```

How can I center one element even with elements aligned on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go... I've added more icons to show you that the snippet is working. Remove them in your actual project.

```css
.rainbow {
  color: blue !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2"></div>
      <div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto rainbow" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model" target="_blank">color</a>dle
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <button class="icons settings-icon">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="icons leaderboard-icon">
              <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="icons question-icon">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-chart-simple"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="icons settings-icon">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="icons leaderboard-icon">
              <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="icons question-icon">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-chart-simple"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="icons settings-icon">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="icons leaderboard-icon">
              <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i>
            </button>
          <button class="icons question-icon">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-chart-simple"></i>
            </button>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```